# Three.js - Trying to understand the vertices array data within a js file

Tags: javascript, three.js, vertices

I am trying to understand the vertices array data within a js file. Does anyone know what all those numbers inside the vertices array are? Are they the position (x,y,z) of each vertex? Here is an [example](http://threejs.org/examples/models/skinned/UCS/umich_ucs.js) of a js file.

Comment: Have you checked if the vertices array is
(x1,y1,z1),
(x2,y2,z2),
(x3,y3,z3)...? http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Core/Geometry Use a for loop to add them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Blender exported JSON files, each of them are coordinates, so they are to be read by 3 (like DNA).

```
[x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2,....,xn, yn, zn]
```